# Считывание определенных символов из файла

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Код определяет количество символов в текстовом документе. Вопрос таков:какую конструкцию нужно добавить, чтобы с файла считывать количество определенных символов?(например только количество букв x, или чисел 5?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
 
int get_size(const char* name)
{   std::ifstream file(name);
    if(!file.is_open()) return -1;
    file.seekg (0, std::ios::end);
    return file.tellg();
}
 
int main()
{   setlocale(0, "");
    ///-------------------------|
    /// Количество символов.    |
    ///-------------------------:
    int s = get_size("my.txt");
    std::cout << s << " символов.\n";
 
    {   std::ofstream o("stat.txt");
        o << s << " символов.\n";
    }
 
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Читайте по одному и считате...

Comment: Вам нужно прочитать весь файл и сверять символы с нужным Вам и производить необходимые вычисления.

Answer (score 2):

Сделай счетчик, затем ты должен пройтись по всему файлу циклом For и проверять каждый символ на равенство той же пятерке или иксу If'ом. Если символ будет равен, то увеличиваешь счетчик на единицу, а после окончания цикла выведи окончательное значение!